# Why doesn't Schedulers.newParallel() from project Reactor stop running after Flux is done emitting elements?

Tags: java, scheduler, project-reactor, flux

I have a primitive `Flux` of `String`s, and run this code in the `main()` method.

```java
package com.example;
    
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.core.scheduler.Schedulers;
import reactor.util.Logger;
import reactor.util.Loggers;
    
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
    
public class Parallel {
    
  private static final Logger log = Loggers.getLogger(Parallel.class.getName());

  private static List<String> COLORS = Arrays.asList("red", "white", "blue");

  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Flux<String> flux = Flux.fromIterable(COLORS);
    flux
      .log()
      .map(String::toUpperCase)
      .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newParallel("sub"))
      .publishOn(Schedulers.newParallel("pub", 1))
      .subscribe(value -> {
        log.info("==============Consumed: " + value);
      });
  }
}
```

If you try to run this code the app never stops running and you need to stop it manually.
If I replace `.newParallel()` with `.parallel()` everything works as expected and the app finishes normally.

Why can't it finish running on its own? Why does it hang?
What is the reason for this behavior?

If you run this code as a JUnit test it works fine and it doesn't hang.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Scheduler` instances that you create yourself with `newXxx` factory methods are created in *non-daemon* mode by default, which means that it can prevent the JVM from exiting.

JUnit calls `System.exit()` when all the tests have run, which explains why the test scenario doesn't hang.

In this context, `Schedulers.newSingle()` and `Schedulers.newParallel()` variants are the worst "offenders", because the threads created are not culled after an inactivity timeout, unlike with `Schedulers.newBoundedElastic()`.

If in a real world scenario you have a well defined application lifecycle, you could store the `Scheduler` instances somewhere (eg. as beans) and ensure each `Scheduler#dispose()` is called at the end of the application lifecycle.

Easier solution: create the `Schedulers` explicitly with `daemon == true` using the relevant factory overload.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is just put the dispose on the complete handler of the subscribe.

```kotlin
package example

import reactor.core.publisher.Flux
import reactor.core.scheduler.Schedulers
import reactor.util.Loggers
import java.util.*

object Parallel

private val log = Loggers.getLogger(Parallel::class.java.name)

private val COLORS = listOf("red", "white", "blue")

fun main() {
    val flux = Flux.fromIterable(COLORS)
    val subScheduler = Schedulers.newParallel("sub")
    val pubScheduler = Schedulers.newParallel("pub", 1)
    flux
        .log()
        .map { obj: String ->
            obj.uppercase(
                Locale.getDefault()
            )
        }
        .subscribeOn(subScheduler)
        .publishOn(pubScheduler)
        .subscribe(
            { value ->
                log.info("==============Consumed: $value")
            },
            { err -> log.error("{}", err.message) },
            {
                subScheduler.dispose()
                pubScheduler.dispose()
            }
        )

}
```